# Cron job twitter

Tags: php, unix, cron, twitter

I have an unusual issue.

I have created a script in PHP which will post on Twitter an automated message. The script works perfectly fine. I have also included a cron job that will re-activate the script every hour.

When I manually refresh the script it works perfectly, I have set an email notification to my cron job every hour so that it'll tell me if the job has succeeded or not. The job (being the automatic refresh of the page) works fine however the response I get is an error.

In short, both my PHP script & cron job works fine seperately however when they come together they do not work.

My cron job command is (I'm on JustHost):

```
php -q /home1/MY_USERNAME/public_html/twitter/index.php
```

Comment: post your cron script.

Comment: It'd be helpful if you can post the error you get.

Comment: Check `/var/log/cron`, `/var/log/messages` and `/var/log/syslog` for cron errors.

Comment: please search here for `[php] cron`. This comes up, seemingly everyday. Good luck.

Comment: @Rainulf I don't have any errors. It works fine. :|

Comment: @cheeyos I don't have any errors. It works fine. :|

Comment: You said the response you get is an error, so there has to have error somewhere; sometimes, it's permission issue with cron.

Comment: @rainulf in my PHP code I have this snippet of code that'll tell me if something has gone wrong, which is:

//Do something if the request was unsuccessful 
if ($response != 200) {echo 'Error 200';}

I only ever get this error when my cron job starts, otherwise if I manually refresh index.php I don't get it & my message tweets successfully.

Comment: please avoid extended discussions of your problem in comments. Edit your question to clarify what you are looking for help with, using proper formatting tools available (I mean the `{}` to keep code samples as-is). Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

first minute of every hour:

```
1 * * * * wget -q --spider --timeout=0 --tries=1 http://yourdomain.com/twitter/index.php
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using wget or curl to call the PHP. Currently you are invoking the script from the php command. It is quite possible that the script is owned by the owner of the virtual server (it looks from the path like you have some kind of user-partitioned setup on your hosting, eg Virtualmin). If this is the case then running the script from a wget or curl will probably work because the user running the script will then be the owner of the script (in your example: 'MY_USERNAME').

This is only a test, but even if it doesn't work it will help eliminate errors with the cron job, narrowin gdown the source of the issue.

You probably know this but you should also secure that script. Currently it is web-accessible, meaning someone could hammer it, filling up your twitter account and sending you email. Cheers!

Comment: Please improve your answer and mention why this may help (script is executed via the webserver, e.g. just like it's the case if someone users accesses it via HTTP)